# Generating Invoices and Updating Database Table Automatically

Tags: php, database, pdf, automation, invoices

I have a possible client with the following tasks:

> Teacher
>   The teacher generates an invoice: at the end of each month the system generates automatically
>   an invoice with the hours worked by the teacher. The invoice is sent to the school in PDF
>   format.

and

> Student
>   View teachers information, telephone number, can email teacher.
>   read/comment the lessons, approves the lessons for billing. if student does not respond lessons
>   automatically approves within 24 hours.

I understand workings of a web application when user is actually using it, clicking the links and triggering some events.
What I don't know how to do is those parts where something has to be done automatically.
How would you solve this, where things have to be done based on time passed?

I would also appreciate for you to tell me how would you generate .pdf in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement the functionality to enable the actions described, then create a cron job, set its frequency to the desired and run your task as part of the cron job. As about generating PDF with php, read [this](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1414-how-to-generate-a-pdf-with-php/).

Comment: Thanks Lajos. I'm surprised that databases don't have something like this implemented by now though.